# Error code 1290 and inability to import data on table

Tags: import, errors

I am running a 5.7.16 version of MySQL on my Windows 8 operating system. I am facing troubles when trying to load datas into a table. I tried with the script

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\LAVORO\xxx\MySqlFiles\xxx.csv' INTO TABLE xxx.vce4 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' ;
```

... but the error code 1290 appears:

```
Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

If I execute the statement:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

... the result is `'secure_file_priv', 'C:\Users\xxx\Dropbox\LAVORO\xxx\MySqlFiles\'.`

I am unable to solve the error code 1290, I tried to use the Table Data Import Wizard, which seemed to work (Import results: `"Table xxx.vce4 has been used"`) BUT `"0 rows imported"`.

What is wrong with this? I really can't figure out how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As per MySQL documentation

**This variable is used to limit the effect of data import and export operations, such as those performed by the LOAD DATA and SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statements and the LOAD_FILE() function. These operations are permitted only to users who have the FILE privilege.**

So one solution is to place your files under the value displayed under this variable

if the directory doesn't exist create it as being displayed and make sure mysql user have access on it.

```
 show variables like '%secure_file_priv%';
```

or change the value in my.ini/cnf file as this variable is read-only and would require a restart

if you want to disable this restriction and can use any directory set it to empty value or change it according to your need

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv=new_path
```

if you want to disable the feature of loading-unloading set it's values to NULL

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The value displayed under this variable is the same mentioned in the LOAD DATA INFILE statement I have tried to run (it means the folder is the same). To disable this set, what should I exactly type in correspondence of the secure-file-priv variable into the my.ini file? secure-file-priv = "" ?

Comment: make sure permissions on folder are sufficient to perform this operation

Comment: how? Anyway I think I'd rather disable the secure-file-priv, in order not to be bound to one directory for future DB creations and analyses

Comment: if you want it to be anywhere just set it to some empty value.. secure_file_priv=''

Comment: I did as you suggested, setting secure_file_priv = "" and now it works. Thank you very much for your help!